# Strange behaviour with mysql and tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I have a strange behaviour in my application

The application normally starts in 30 seconds but sometimes it takes 7 minutes to start.

It starts in 30 minutes again only when I restart mysql.

Mysql is installed using

> `apt-get install mysql-server`

and I did not change any of its default settings.

Can anyone please just guide me where to look and what should I suspect here?

Thnx

Comment: Have you shut down things cleanly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this might be something to do with uncommited transactions. As I have had something similar to this.

Another option might to look at any dead locking happening.

Im assuming when the application starts it immediately accesses the database.

First will usually be successful, then because of uncommited transactions, the second and subsequent starts of the Application will result in it hanging for a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Get your Tomcat's PID with [`jps`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html) and check what your threads do (or waiting for) with [`jstack`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html).